# ModuleNotFoundError but my module is there

Tags: python-3.x, python-import, python-module

I'm tryng to run the "run.py" archive in the terminal.

My files structure is the following:

```
==pythonProject1
  |
   ==somapi
     |
      ==file1
      ==file2
      ==file3
      ==__init__.py
      ==api.py
      ==config.py
      ==run.py
```

When i try to run it in terminal, both "somapi\run.py" or "run.py" it doesn't work. It delivers the ModuleNotFoundError to somapi, and tells me run isn't a command in my computer wtf. My brain is melting

The import in run.py is:

```
from somapi.api import app
```

The error message reference is about this import.

Comment: Hi! What is the directory from which you are executing the command? Also, what is the full command?